# Clarification on Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Part I Explanation

Tags: calculus

I'm reading through an older Calculus textbook ("Calculus" 2nd Edition by James Stewart published in 1991).  In its explanation of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Part I it uses [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPYzh.png) and states the following:

> If we take $f(t) = t$ and $a=0$ then, using an earlier exercise we
> have $$g(x)=\int_{0}^{x} t \; dt = \frac{x^2}{2}$$

All of that makes sense to me, as I did (and fully understand) the "earlier exercise".  The very next sentence in the book states:

> Notice that $g'(x)=x$, that is, $g' = f$.

Okay, I totally get that the derivative of $g(x)$ is $x$, but how is it that $g' = f$ ????

Comment: What is $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that

$$g(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}, \quad g'(x)=x,$$

and so, as $f(x)=x$, it follows that

$$f(x)=x=g'(x),$$

i.e. $g'=f$. What this shows you is how the fundamental theorem of calculus part 1 works. It tells you that

$$f(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_a^x f(t)~\mathrm{d}t,$$

and in your example this becomes

\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x \\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_0^x t~\mathrm{d}t \\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}g(x) \\
&=g'(x).
\end{align*}

Comment: Sorry, for being a little slow here...  How is it that $f(x) = x$ ?

Comment: @TerenceD You wrote yourself that the example began with "If we take $f(t)=t$". This is the same as saying that we simply define $f(x)=x$, i.e. everything else we get because we choose that $f(x)=x$.

Comment: Right, I guess what confuses me is that in [the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPYzh.png) it's clear that $f(t)$ is some function where $f(t) != t$ yet then when the book says $f(t) = t$ that would be a graph like [this](https://ibb.co/J5gTWKc) a diagonal line through the origin bisecting quadrants I and III....  I suppose the book starts talking about taking $f(t)=t$ I need to not think this $f$ is the same as the $f$ in the figure where $y=f(t)$.  Agree?

Comment: @TerenceD I think the figure is meant to represent a more general case because the fundamental theorem of calculus is not specific to when $f(x)=x$. So the part where $f(x)=x$ is just a specific example, while the figure (which is not really relevant to this specific problem) shows you an illustration of how it looks in general. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think that makes sense.  Would you agree that if the book had a figure for this part it would look like [this](https://ibb.co/0GnHGMn)?

Comment: @TerenceD Yep that looks right!

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks, totally makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You defined $f(t) = t$, so $g'(x) = x = f(x)$, meaning $g' = f$.

Answer (score 1):

1. > If we take $f(t) = t$

   In other words, $f(u)=u.\tag1$
2. > Notice that $g'(x)=x$

   In other words, $g'(u)=u.\tag2$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2):$ $$g'(u)=f(u),$$

> that is, $g' = f$.